# How to reverse engineer/extract code ATmega32

Tags: arduino, reverse-engineering, microcontroller, decompiling, atmega

I need help to extract code from an ATmega32a microcontroller. I have knowledge about hardware, registers, assembly stuff but I'm not even close to expert about embedded systems. Even though I know reverse engineering is not for beginners still I want to learn at least basic concepts which I couldn't find on the web.

How can I communicate with the chip, extract code and decompile it?
What are the hardware/software requirements for this? (Assuming code is not protected.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answers are on the web in the datasheet for the part.   What part of that did you not understand?

Comment: Define decompile.  The compilation process (assuming this was compiled code) permanently removes information, how do you plan on recovering that lost information?

Comment: I know that there are ways to retrieve the program as machine code. For now I think that'll be enough for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can never get the c code from inside the Atmega32 chip, as the chip never knows the c code.

You can however get the machine code out of the chip using the following command from the terminal

```
avrdude -c <programmer name> -p m32 -U flash:r:read_firmware.hex:i
```

For this you will have to install avrdude into your system. Read more [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pocket-avr-programmer-hookup-guide#using-avrdude-via-command-line)
You will also need an SPI programmer for atmega chips. My personal favorite for this is the [pocket programmer from sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pocket-avr-programmer-hookup-guide/all)

You can then go through the hex file via a text editor and try to understand the machine code using the Atmega32 datasheet.

Personally, I have never felt it was worth the effort.

Comment: After reading it, you can disassemble it with a command like `avr-objdump -D -m avr5 read_firmware.hex`.

Comment: Although avr-objdump can attempt a disassembly of the code you read with avrdude... it's lack of "smarts" and brute-force methodology can make it less than optimal as a reverse engineering tool. You may get better results with: http://cutter.re http://radare.org http://ghidra-sre.org or http://hex-rays.com/products/ida